# Laravel - File upload doesn't seem to allow all types of files for some reason

Tags: laravel, file-upload, controller

My application denies access to upload files with certain extensions for some reason.
It prints out the error:

```
fopen(C:\wamp64\www\storage\app\public/wrdjxF3EMbtGCUyXjSEWH5zeAu822ACeKikLPaCT.): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

The file types that have given out this error so far are: **.msg** and **.txt**.
I have no clue what causes this problem, other file types seem to work fine.

The controller function that handles the file uploads:

```
if($request->hasFile('document'))
{
    $files = $request->file('document');
    foreach($files as $file){
        if($file){
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $size = $file->getClientSize();
            $size = number_format($size / 1048576,2);
            $path = $file->store('public');
            Document::create([
                'report_id' => $id,
                'report_type' => "App\VisitingReport",
                'file_path' => $path,
                'file_name' => $name,
                'file_size' => $size.' MB'
            ]);  
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

I'm running this on a Windows computer using WAMP.

I am convinced that it has something to do with the permissions indeed. I'm already a step further, the file gets uploaded but this time without the extension.

Answer (score 0):

can you paste here what permissions you see for other file types and `.txt` after uploads. Run `ls -la` in the place where these files are stored and permission should be on far left. something like `rwxr-wr-w`. Paste here so that at least it can give a clue on what could be the issue.

Otherwise, once `.txt` file is uploaded you can run `chmod 777 some.txt` and see if you are still getting permission issue. If you aren't getting permission issue anymore than it's somehow creating `.txt` file with different permission. But it's not a good idea to do `777` for anything :D. But at least now you know what the problem is.

If permissions are the problem then here is a wonderful answer on this topic

[How to set up file permissions for Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel)

Good luck :)
I'm not an expert just trying to help

Comment: I should add that I am using Windows and WAMP :P.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with this error, but I don't know it works for you or not.
put this in your .env file

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER = public
```

and link the public folder with storage folder with this command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

I hope it works.